# Sharepoint API: method ProjectData does not return Project, exact ID inside

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, project-online

(!)
Has anybody the contacts of Sharepoint API TEAM?
Thanks in advance.

#### Category Bug:

Customer has projects: https://***.sharepoint.com/teams/npt/Projects.aspx.

He sometimes creates/publishes new projects. Then he wants to get them by executing this URL/action, for example:

```
https://***.sharepoint.com/teams/npt/_api/ProjectData/[en-US]/Projects?$filter=ProjectLastPublishedDate gt datetime'2019-11-05T12:18:00.000Z'
```

#### Expected or Desired Behavior:

He expects to get the all published projects limited by **ProjectLastPublishedDate**.

We have an example Project TestProject (ID - 5eb03036-945b-e911-94bc-4851b7ad0443).
Customer Published it on `2019-11-05T12:19:00.000Z` (UTC). And after that he wanted to get this project from method:

```
_api/ProjectData/[en-US]/Projects with filter by ProjectLastPublishedDate
```

But he could not. We got the empty response.

#### Steps to Reproduce:

This bug not related to all projects and not happens all time.

- Publish Project
- Wait about 1 minute.
- Get by URL

#### Submission Guidelines:

Maybe this project have some features and is different from other? But customer has some another Project which have similar behavior.
Maybe Sharepoint saves this Project to another storage with some worse ping?

Can you provide us the Documentation or this Action and what projects he returns?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried with /ProjctServer/ endpoint?

```
/_api/ProjectServer/Projects?$filter=LastPublishedDate gt datetime'2019-11-05T12:18:00.000Z'
```

works well for me (SP 2016 OnPrem CU 09/2019).

PS:
I can't even find any data about publishing of project using ProjectData

Comment: Do you have a documentation for ProjectServer action?
We use ProjectData already long time. 
Specified issue is not related all projects. Customer has not problem with almost projects.

Comment: I'm afraid a documentation for REST API of Project Server doesn't even exist... https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/project-javascript-api/jj669820(v=office.15) this all I finde and use. Still pretty bad but better than nothing.

Comment: Has anybody the contacts of Sharepoint API TEAM?
Thanks in advance.